# Rewriting HTTP to HTTPS in Nginx, using .conf settings

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, url-rewriting

What I'm missing here?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    if ($scheme = http) { rewrite ^(.*)$ https://domain.com$1 permanent; }
    if ($host ~* ^www\.) { rewrite ^(.*)$ https://domain.com$1 permanent; }
    ...
}
```

It gives me redirect loop error.

Comment: Is your SSL certificate for `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`?

Comment: Yes, it's for www also. But actually, the second rewrite `removes` the www.

Comment: Yes, I know. The reason I asked is to know if you'd get a certificate warning for requests to `https://www.domain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot at this with the information available. When redirecting all requests from http to https, a separate server block for port 80 is a good idea. Similarly, when redirecting all requests from one hostname to another, a separate server block for each hostname is also a good idea.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com;

    ...
}
```

So we're listening on port 80 for either hostname and redirecting to `https://domain.com` and also listening on port 443 for `https://www.domain.com` and redirecting those requests to `https://domain.com` as well. This keeps your Nginx configuration clear and easy to read.

**Important:** Please note that if your SSL certificate does not include `www.domain.com`, then requests to `https://www.domain.com` will result in a certificate error and rather nasty browser warnings. In this case, you should replace your certificate with one that includes both hostnames.

Comment: Yeah, I've saw a lot of tutorials with a separate block. So it's not possible to be on the same? Thanks.

Comment: It should be possible if you add `server_name domain.com www.domain.com;` inside the block. However, doing it that way is **not** recommended: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if